# Gorm delete but keep ID increasing

Tags: database, go, go-gorm

I want have unique and autoincremental ids on my gorm database, even from previously created and deleted entries.

I have this model in my database:

```
type Books struct {
    ID            uint `json:"-" gorm:"autoIncrement"`
    Name          string `json:"name"`
    Author        uint `json:"author"`
}
```

Lets say I create 3 books, if I run `db.Find(&Books{})` the output will be something like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "name1",
    author: 123,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "name2",
    author: 123,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "name3",
    author: 123,
  },
]
```

If I delete Book 3 by ID, doing this: `db.Delete(&Books{}, 3)`, as the documentation says: https://gorm.io/docs/delete.html#Delete-with-primary-key, the book 3 is deleted.

So, if I make another Find, I will get this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "name1",
    author: 123,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "name2",
    author: 123,
  },
]
```

The problem comes out when I create one more book, because it will have 3 as ID.

I would like that the new created book would have ID 4, instead of 3, so I will have ids 1, 2, and 4.

The output from Find I would like to have is:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "name1",
    author: 123,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "name2",
    author: 123,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "name4",
    author: 123,
  },
]
```

So that's basically my problem.

I also thought of doing something like:

```
type Books struct {
    ID            uint `json:"-" gorm:"autoIncrement"`
    Name          string `json:"name"`
    Author        uint `json:"author"`
    Deleted       bool `json:"-"`
}
```

And then, when I make a Find, i would filter the deleted=true ones... But that would take too much space on my database file, so I would like another solution.

Comment: Its not by GORM, it comes from database!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @mkopriva im using sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your *gorm struct* is:

```
type Books struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name          string `json:"name"`
    Author        uint `json:"author"`
}
```

Where **gorm.Model** gives you fields: *ID, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, DeletedAt*

When you do a `db.Delete(&Books, 3)` it will do a soft-delete, which means the *DeletedAt* will be updated from `null` to a `timestamp`. This does not physically removes the record from the DB. You can still fetch this record by `db.Unscoped().Find(&Books)`

In order to *permanently delete* the record: `db.Unscoped().Delete(&Books,3)`

I guess (I haven't tried this yet!) after permanently deleting the record, your ID sequence should fall in place.

Comment: Have you find out if it actually works or not?

Answer (score 2):

This is because the database generates a new sequence generator on id in book table and whenever you add a book, it will take the current value from sequencer , add it to the row and increment it for next value.

There is no way to go back and fill the id deleted from row. And this is something not to worry about. when presenting it to the user, dont show the misordered numbers just display 1,2,3 and for performing operations like update, delete use this id.

Or you can use UUID instead of integer

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood OP's question, but isn't what you are describing exactly what OP says he would like to happen but does not happen? Doesn't he say that after deleting Book id=3 and then doing an insert, the new Book has id=3 and *not* id=4, but OP *wants* id=4 and not id=3?

Comment: well yes, OP want id = 4, ant thats what i tried to answer. sequence generator will keep incrementing, so you will get 4. But now reading the question again, he is saying that he *will* get id = 3, which is not possible to get.